# Can I dip Stainless Steel Heat Exchangers in Milk?

Tags: thermodynamics, material-science, physical-chemistry

I am heating milk using hot water through a coil heat exchanger. The heat exchanger is made of stainless steel 316. It is dipped in the milk.

Is there any risk of contamination of milk from the setup? Any issue of corrosion of the heat exchanger?

There are alternate ways as well but this seems the most efficient. I can go for steam/water jackets.

Comment: This belongs on Engineering SE, not Physics.

Comment: @DKNguyen I am happy to learn here, see below, that being stainless against water is not the same as being stainless against milk, MILK!

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons for the development of type 316 and 316L stainless steels was their superior corrosion resistance in milk exposure, so you should be OK.